# php-mysql executes extra explain sql

Tags: php, mysql

I've two servers that running the same php application code and pointing to same database. One server is redhat and the other one is ubuntu. But the one in ubuntu seems to run extra explain sql when php code executes some sql query.

My application code is the same in both servers. I even turned off the following two settings in php.ini in ubuntu but it still has those explain sql.

mysql.trace_mode = off
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = Off

Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Unless you can get something more specific in terms of *code*, this really is a question for the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No this is not for dba site. It has something to do with php. If you read my info as I said my application code written in php is the same on both server and they point to the same mysql server. It's just when execute from 1 of the application server it will execute extra explain sql.

Comment: It's obvious it has nothing to do with DBA. It's more to php.

Comment: It's obvious to you, but I have no idea what you're talking about. What "application code" are you running? Is it using a framework that has a development-mode add-on that does automatic `EXPLAIN` calls?

Comment: No it's zend framework but I've it on 2 servers. The first server doesn't have explain sql when web application load. I simply just copy all the zend framework and lib, etc into this new servers But install php. The first one has php 5.3.3. in redhat while the 2nd one has php 5.5.9 in ubuntu. Then they point to same db server. So that's why I thought must be something in php settings. I played around those one I mentioned earlier but no luck.

Comment: You're going to have to do more work to narrow down the circumstances under which this runs. A bare-bones PDO script does this? Only your application does?

Comment: Yea tried running command line php script that uses mysqli and seems still have explain sql. Then also tried another script uses zend framework similar like the web application and used zend db then run it from command line then still has explain. I thought those setting in php.ini will do the trick but it's weird that it has no impact. I thought maybe others who install ubuntu, apache, php may have similar issue but seems nothing related to this out there.

Comment: Maybe an exorcism is called for here. Spirit of a long-lost developer inhabiting your system? There's something very odd about this.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out. It's something due to a monitor tool, new relic, I've on the server. And there's a setting newrelic.transaction_tracer.explain_enabled = false that will trigger explain sql. Thanks for helping.